# Joomla site behind login, images folder is accessible

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

Got a problem with Joomla. I've made a site completely behind a login. This means that to access the site, you need to fill out a user + password. This all goes well, menu's are restricted to "Registered" access and thus nobody can access these pages.

My problem however lies in the images folder map. In that folder I save my files, PDF, images, etc. But these hyperlinks are publicly available to everybody, which shouldn't be the case. How can I fix this? I cannot set the images folder behind registered so.

Comment: Possible dupiicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646078/stop-files-being-accessed-directly

Comment: @Huub S htaccess may be the solution for it.

Comment: This is not about programming. It would be appropriate for [joomla.se] which takes all kinds of Joomla questions.

Comment: Okay, posted it there. @Toretto I also thought I could do it with a htaccess but a lot of troubles I got with that